# Sierpinsky triangle OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, xcode4.5

I'm trying to learn OpenGL. I tried some code I found in this [book](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/) but the output of the program is just a white screen, the output should be the Sierpinski triangle.

What could be wrong? I'm developing on Mac OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.5

```
#include "Angel.h"
#include <iostream>

const int numPoints = 5000;
typedef vec2 point2;

void init(){

    point2 points[numPoints];
    point2 vertices[3] = {
        point2(-1.0, -1.0), point2(0.0, 1.0), point2(1.0, -1.0)
    };

    points[0] = point2(0.25, 0.5);

    for (int k = 1; k < numPoints; k++) {
        int j = rand()%3;
        points[k] = (points[k-1]+vertices[j])/2.0;
    }

    GLuint program = InitShader("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);

    GLuint abuffer;
    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &abuffer);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(abuffer);

    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

}


void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numPoints);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);

    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you attach te shader program?  It won't work without it.

Comment: How do I attach the shader? I really don't know anything. I thought this lines `GLuint program = InitShader("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);` where related to the shader.

Comment: @MichaelIV The book is intended for beginners, but the codes are written for windows, I'm just trying to make them run under OS X.

Comment: @BRabbit27 You're correct that the `InitShader` routine takes care of all the steps (including attaching shaders) required to get shaders to work.  It's a shortcut that's discussed in Angel's book.

Comment: @radical7 so what could I be missing, I mean, I checked and rechecked the code. I mean I really enjoy  reading that book but it's a little bit discouraging the fact that I cannot build the example.

Comment: Just a guess here: try removing the APPLE on the `gl*VertexArraysAPPLE` routines.  Vertex array objects are required in 3.2.  You're using the APPLE extension version of them, which while similar, isn't the same.  If that doesn't work, then try removing the GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE, which will switch you back to something like GL version 2.1, which is a less restrictive OpenGL environment.  If you're using the shaders from Angel's book, they should compile in the lower version.

Comment: I got the following message `Use of undeclared identifier 'gl*VertexArrays'.` if I remove the `APPLE` suffix. Now If I remove the `GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE` I got the following error from the InitShader function `vertex.glsl failed to compile:
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '150' is not supported`

Comment: Sorry - the '*' in there was meant as a wildcard abbreviation.  In your original program, switch `glGenVertexArraysAPPLE` to just `glGenVertexArrays`, and `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE` to `glBindVertexArray.  As for the shader errors, OpenGL 2.1 supports version 120.  Since these are such simple shaders, you could just change the version number.  FYI, each version of OpenGL has its own accompanying GLSL shader version (e.g., OpenGL 3.2 uses 150).

Comment: Yes, I understood it as a wildcard. Now, I changed the version to 120 and the error reads: `vertex.glsl failed to compile:
ERROR: 0:3: Invalid qualifiers 'in' in global variable context
ERROR: 0:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'vPosition'
`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23419/discussion-between-brabbit27-and-radical7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally !
The code is complete, the shaders are attached as they should be.

There's a problem with a `.h` files included in `Angel.h`, instead of having `<OpenGL/OpenGL.h>` it should be `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`. The second thing to change is to remove the `APPLE` suffix to the functions `glGenVertexArrayAPPLE` and `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE`.

Apparently there's a problem with Apple and their implementation of OpenGL, probably not all the stuff is compatible with what they have, but I let that topic to the experts, if there's someone out there please clarify this.

Comment: U.G. happens, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you seem to miss the shader program attachment stage.When using programmable pipeline you have to supply at least one vertex and fragment shaders compiled into shader program.Then in the render loop ,before calling glDrawArrays() or any other geometry related method you must bind the shader program via glUseProgram .Otherwise your GPU has no idea how to process the vertex data.Take a look at [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) great tutorial which explains in very detail all you need to know to get started with modern OpenGL.I think though ,you will have to use extension for some of the API methods when working on OSX as it supports GL 3.2 if I recall correctly.

> How do I attach the shader? I really don't know anything.

Well , look , you MUST know how to do it otherwise you can't proceed with writing OpenGL application.Read the tutorials carefully to get a solid grasp of how shader programs work and why you need them.

Comment: I tried to start with the tutorial you suggested, seems very interesting, thanks. I have a problem building the stuff tough. `==== Building freeglut (debug) ====
Creating lib
Creating obj/Debug
freeglut_callbacks.c
In file included from src/freeglut_callbacks.c:28:
In file included from include/GL/freeglut.h:17:
include/GL/freeglut_std.h:120:10: fatal error: 'GL/gl.h' file not found
#include <GL/gl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [obj/Debug/freeglut_callbacks.o] Error 1
make: *** [freeglut] Error 2`

Comment: As I said, I'm working on a Mac,I know that the OpenGL header is `OpenGL/OpenGL.h`